# jsPDF - compatibility issues in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, jspdf

jsPDF doesn't work well with the latest version of Firefox. It does not let me to download the PDF. Is there a fix on this? I tried downloading the latest version of jsPDF.

**EDIT:**

- My FF version is 32.0.3
- I don't get any error messages.

This is the code that "downloads" the pdf. It works well in IE and Chrome:

So I think it has nothing to do with the code. What I want to know is how can I download the pdf in Firefox.

```
function appendDataToPDF(div, doc, top)
{
    html2canvas(div, {
        background: '#fff',
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL();
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, top, parseInt($(div).css("width"), 10), parseInt($(div).css("height"), 10));

            if(top > 240)
            {
                doc.addPage();
                top = 27;
            }

            div = $(div).next();

            if(div.length === 0)
            {
                doc.save('doc.pdf');
            }
            else
            {
                if(div.get(0).nodeName === 'BR')
                    div = $(div).next();

                appendDataToPDF(div, doc, top);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry, but this question is much too unspecific to be answerable. Which one exactly is the "latest" version of your FF? What do you do to "download the PDF"? What error messages do you get? Do you have any code to show us how you are using jspdf?

Comment: So, are there any errors when this runs in FF? What kind of debugging have you done, is `div.length` really `0` and `doc.save()` actually executed?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, they're actually executed. I placed an alert inside that if, before the doc.save() function. What's weird is that after I placed the alert, it started to download the pdf, but not always... Sometimes it shows the dialogue to save the pdf, sometimes not..

Comment: Now i placed the alert after the doc.save(), and it always downloads...

Comment: Should I give U the +50 rep? :P

Comment: No, thanks, I didn't really solve the problem - and it still doesn't work if you omit the `alert()` I hope?! I would suspect this to be some race condition issue that got covered by waiting during the `alert` is open, but I can't tell…

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work without the `alert()`, on FF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue lies within the execution of the `doc.save()`. The document is not ready yet, when the `save()` command is invoked. Try to set a timeout and it should work.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    doc.save(filename);
}, timeout);
```

Comment: Will use this instead of the alert().

Answer (score 2):

I just placed an `alert()` after the `doc.save()` function and now the download works. You could try this solution if you run into the same problem.

Comment: Hm, maybe try `void(0)` instead of `alert()` to make it less annoying (no popup).

Answer (score 0):

One thread is going on related this issue, may be you will get fix here.
https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/3391

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31588382)